# Shrinking Disk - safe to delete LocationProvider folder?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8, partitioning

I currently have a 600GB partition on my HDD, which has 100GB used. I want to shrink it down to 200GB, however when I try to do so, the "unmovable file" error comes up.

Using Application Logs, I have determined the file to be `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\LocationProvider\edbres00001.jrs::$DATA`. However, when attempting to access the file or running the `fsutil volume querycluster`, I get an access denied message, even as administrator.

My question is, should I delete this folder (is it safe to), and if so, how? If I shouldn't, are there any other steps I could possibly take?

Thank you!

Comment: Rename that folder, check if any problem occurs, if not then delete.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the file is unmovable that means its been locked or in use which would go to suggestion you should not delete it.

Instead search for Location in control panel and disable the location provider in settings. You might need to restart after that.

You can't delete unmovable files for the same reason they can't be moved.